# How to properly run a bot with a flask webapp

Tags: python, flask

The goal is to run a bot script with multiple files that needs to share the database with flask webapp

`models.py`

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(  db.Model ):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100))
    pass_hash = db.Column(db.String(1000))
```

`app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
from models import db, User 
from test import start_bot
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///sth.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def get_info():
    return "this is a test"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot_thread = Thread(target=start_bot).start()
    app.run()
```

`bot.py` this is the main file of the bot simplified to a single file

```
from time import time,sleep
from models import db 
from models import User

def access_db():    
    all_usrs = User.query.all()
    return (str(all_usrs))

def start_bot():
    while True:
        print (f"Current Time : {time()}")
        sleep(3)
        access_db()
```

Now the bot needs to access the database and return a list of all the users in that db and it needs to edit add or delete from that database
the error

```
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

the bot seems to be out of app context I tried to run the thread using `with app.app_context():` but this does not seem to solve the problem

How do you solve such problem

Answer (score 1):

Okay you can try this but I don't think it is a good solution

in `app.py` add this

```py
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///sth.db"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

move the `from test import start_bot` to the line before the bot_thread or this will throw an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

in `bot.py` change the `access_db` to

```py
from app import create_app


def access_db():
    with create_app().app_context():
    
        all_usrs = User.query.all()
        return (str(all_usrs))
```

as I said this is not the best solution but it works let me know if you face any errors